# Cannot import Renderer2 component in Angular.

Tags: angular, typescript, components, primeng, renderer

I'm trying to import Renderer2 using:

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

However, I get the error

```
"Module '"project/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
```

I'm unsure why this is happening. I'm using PrimeNG ([here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/)) which contains a component called ConfirmDialog which contains the same import statement, yet I don't run into any issues with it. I've seen posts that suggest Renderer2 is only compatible with Angular 4 - I'm currently using @angular/core 2.2.4. If Angular 4 is required, then shouldn't the ConfirmDialog of PrimeNG break (it doesn't)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that Renderer2 is only used in angular angular/core 4.x.x Project .If you upgraded the primeNG latest version "Sure Will not run according to the upgrading due to angular 4 version". So you need either Upgrade the project if you urgently need Renderer2. Instead you can use angular2 Renderer

Comment: Completely forgot to check the version of PrimeNG I was actually using. I'm actually using 2.0.6 which uses the component Renderer. I was basing my question off of PrimeNG's latest github repo which is currently implemented for Angular 4, hence the use of Renderer2.